# How can I resolve Vetur/Vuelidate error "'validate' does not exist in type 'ComponentOptions<Vue [etc.]"?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2, vuelidate, vetur

**QUESTION:** How can I resolve error `'validations' does not exist in type 'ComponentOptions<Vue [etc.]` while using Vetur with Typescript also installed, all in VSCode?

**BACKGROUND:** I attempted to introduce Vuelidate into a single-file Vue component (by adding a `validations` property as per [the docs](https://vuelidate.js.org/#examples)). The project containing that component has TypeScript installed so that Vetur's intellisense is improved (but the `<script>` sections are using JavaScript). After introducing the `validations` prop, Vetur was displaying an error with the message highlighted in the above question, and intellisense was breaking for methods (such as `mount()`) that were calling other methods.

**CODE:** My code basically looks like the sample below, but one would need to install TypeScript to reproduce the Vetur error:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      name: '',
    }
  },
  validations: {
    name: {
      required,
      minLength: minLength(4)
    },
  }
}
```

**WHAT HAVE I TRIED:** I tried adding `@ts-ignore` to the `validations` property, but intellisense is still broken for methods calling other methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is:

- run `npm install --save-dev @types/vuelidate`
- restart VSCode

Comment: I also added `"types": [ "vuelidate" ]` to tsconfig.json